# Find closest dimensions (length, width, height) in excel

Tags: excel, dimensions

So, there are different plastic cases: model and inner dimensions (Length x Width x Height). I need find the closest option based on:

1. inner dimensions which are put in G3:I3 -> the cell J3 should display the closest model
2. the model of case which is put in the cell K3 and in the cell L3 should find the closest model from other positions in the array.

I have added 3 positions so far but there are thousand+ of them. Would really appreciate if you could help me with that.

I uploaded my [excel](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mfK2dE5sIv5VECDhGDsOo1WfC4cFYX3R?usp=sharing) file to google drive for further reference.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define closest dimensions. For example I created a formula that sums up the absolute deviations of each dimension from the input values of the colored cells and looks for the minimum. Put this into Cell J3 in your example worksheet.

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:B4-G3)+ABS(C2:C4-H3)+ABS(D2:D4-I3)),(ABS(B2:B4-G3)+ABS(C2:C4-H3)+ABS(D2:D4-I3)),0))
```

**Array Formula: press CTRL + Shift + Enter to enter the formula**